# Text next to image margin

Tags: css

I have this result:

```
<div class="news" id="1" style="width: 350px; height: 100px;">
  <p style="float: left;"><img src="images/news.png" width="60" height="60" style="" /></p>
  <p style="margin-left: 10px;"><span id="newsdate" style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #333;">Posted at 5:12 PM, 17/4/2014</span><br>
  <span style="text-align: justify; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #333;">my text here blab lab la wiiihaaaaa why isn't margin coming?</span></p>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YEwUZ/494/

Why isn't `margin-left` working on the text? I want to put a `margin` between the image and the text.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YEwUZ/501/ add the margin to the p tag instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both elements don't have float applied then the margin is against the side of the container instead of against the next element.

You have two choices:

1. Include the width of the image in the margin as described by @web-tiki
2. Add a float: left; to the paragraph element.

A side note you may find that the paragraph will wrap to be under the image unless you increase the size of the container.

A working fiddle: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YEwUZ/499/)**

```
<div class="news" id="1" style="width: 400px; height: 100px;">
    <p style="float: left;"><img src="images/news.png" width="60" height="60" style="" /></p>
    <p style="margin-left: 10px; float:left"><span id="newsdate" style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #333;">Posted at 5:12 PM, 17/4/2014</span><br>
        <span style="text-align: justify; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #333;">my text here blab lab la wiiihaaaaa why isn't margin coming?</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Man, inline styling - seriously?

Change your code to this and it'll work

```
<div class="news" id="1" style="width: 350px; height: 100px;">
                        <img src="images/news.png" width="60" height="60" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;" />
                        <p style="margin-left: 10px;"><span id="newsdate" style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #333;">Posted at 5:12 PM, 17/4/2014</span><br>
                        <span style="text-align: justify; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #333;">my text here blab lab la wiiihaaaaa why isn't margin coming?</span></p>
                </div>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/YEwUZ/500/)

Comment: Jeevan Jose it's just for testing purposes than I add everything in file, Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use inline-styling here:
http://jsfiddle.net/YEwUZ/502/

But if you would like to do it correctly here is the code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="news" id="1" style="">
    <p class="image">
        <img src="images/news.png" width="60" height="60" />
    </p>

    <p>
    <span class="newsdate">Posted at 5:12 PM, 17/4/2014</span><br>
    <span class="content">my text here blab lab la wiiihaaaaa why isn't margin coming?</span>
    </p>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.news {width: 350px; height: 100px;}

.news .newsdate {font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #333;}

.news .content {text-align: justify; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #333;}

.news .image {float:left;margin-right:10px;}
```

So much cleaner! [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YEwUZ/503/)

You could also use the `+ Selector`:

http://jsfiddle.net/YEwUZ/507/